# XamlParseException...DeferredBinaryDeserializerExtension

Tags: wpf, xaml, exception, staticresource

When trying to draw a Rectangle in xaml I get following cryptic runtime error:

```
'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.DeferredBinaryDeserializerExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '364' and line position '18'.
```

The code snippet is:

```
<Rectangle Fill="MyGreenBrush"
           Width="10"
           Height="10"/>
```

update: 
and in some Resource section:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyGreenBrush" Color="Green"/>
```

Comment: what is **MyGreenBrush**?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that I forgot to use StaticResource.
The correct snippet is:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource MyGreenBrush}"
           Width="10"
           Height="10"/>
```